# How do you prove that something is asymptotically normal when you don't know the parameters?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n = f(Y_n, Z_n, ...)$ be some sequence of random variables that depend in some weird way on some other variables.

If a question asks me to show that $X_n$ is asymptotically normal with these and these parameters, then the approach is quite easy. I simply plug those parameters into the *definition* of what asymptotic normality means, and then I work backwards to the CLT.

However, if I don't *know* the parameters, if they are not provided, then what do I do? I can't plug in the parameters in the definition and work my way backwards to the CLT, because I do not know the parameters?

For example, if $X_n = 1/n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i $, $Y_i$ are iid, and I need to show that this converges asymptotically to a normal distribution with mean $EY_1$ and variance $VY_1 /n$, then I simply write $\sqrt{n} ( \frac{1}{n} \sum Y_i - EY_1)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ( \sum Y_i - EY_1)$ and the result thus follows directly from CLT.

But if I did not know that the distribution to which we asymptotically converge has mean $EY_1$ and variance $VY_1 /n$, then how would I work backwards? In this case, it's still easy, but what if it is more complicated?

Comment: There is no general answer. It is probably best if you indicate exactly the definition of $X_n, Y_n, Z_n, \ldots$.